# vuejs treeselect - conditional checkbox

Tags: select, vue.js, vuejs2, treeview

I'm using this plugin: https://vue-treeselect.js.org/

I would like to conditionally disable checkbox for some specific nodes.
For example, here I don't want 'a' to be checkable.  (only 'a', the rest should be checkable)
https://jsfiddle.net/Lv6ajf0t/

```
<div id="app">
  <treeselect :options="options" :multiple="true"></treeselect>
</div>

<script>
    Vue.component('treeselect', VueTreeselect.Treeselect);
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        options: [{id: 'e', label:'e', children: [{id: 'f', label:'f'}]},
          {id:'a', label:'a', children: [
            {id: 'c', label:'c'}]}, {id: 'd', label:'d'}
        ]
      }
    }) 
</script>
```

I couldn't find a way in the docs. Help?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense that the children of a disabled node would be enabled. The library doesn't support what you want.

Comment: Doesn't make sense? why? I need to use the top nodes as 'menu' nodes, since I have a large menu. So the user should (mostly) choose from the leafs. There is actually the option `disableBranchNodes`, which is close to what I want. As I've said I don't need to show the disabled checkboxes, I just don't want them at all in some nodes.

Comment: any solution on this?

Answer (score 1):

I updated your code https://jsfiddle.net/fazanaka/cpvp989z/1/

Just need to add

```
isDisabled: true
```

Comment: it disables 'c' as well, I need just to disable 'a' (or better, just remove the checkbox..)

Comment: @user3599803 In this case you can move 'C' up and then disable A

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with `c` also being disabled (since it is a nested child of `a`), the docs say to use: `isDisabled:true`

https://vue-treeselect.js.org/#disable-item-selection

Comment: I need just 'a' to be disabled, I would want something like isDisabled for a single node